# Python when iterating through two dictionaries and creating a new one from them some elements are sorted wrong

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries. One has an ID as the key (Film ID) and a string containing some names as the value (actors that played in this film), like this

```
fid_description = {1000: 'Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman, Bob Gunton, Wialliam Sadler', 
                   1001: 'Marlon Brando, Al Pacino, James Caan, Diane Keaton', 
                   1002: 'Al Pacino, Robert De Niro, Robert Duvall, Diane Keaton', 
                   1003: 'Christian Bale, Heath Ledger, Aaron Eckhart, Michael Caine', 
                   1004: 'Henry Fonda, Lee J', 
                   1005: 'Liam Neeson, Ralph Fiennes, Ben Kingsley, Caroline Goodall'}
```

The other dict also has an ID as the key and as values a list containing the first and last names of actors as a string, like this

```
dict_actors = {10000: ['Tim', 'Robins'], 10001: ['Morgan', 'Freeman'], 
10002: ['Bob', 'Gunton'], 10003: ['William', 'Sadler'], 10004: ['Marlon', 'Brando'], 
10005: ['Al', 'Pacino'], 10006: ['James', 'Caan'], 10007: ['Diane', 'Keaton'], 
10008: ['Robert', 'De Niro'], 10009: ['Robert', 'Duvall'], 
10010: ['Christian', 'Bale'], 10011: ['Heath', 'Ledger'], 
10012: ['Aaron', 'Eckhart'], 10013: ['Michael', 'Caine'], 
10014: ['Henry', 'Fonda'], 10015: ['Lee', 'J']
```

Now sorry for posting so much from my dicts but the output containing the ID 10015 of the second dict is what I can't explain to myself.

So what I want to do now is to create a new dict, which as a key contains the actor ID and as values a list of the film IDs in which the actor had a role. I wrote the following code for that:

```
aid_fid = {}
for k, v in fid_description.items():
    for key, value in dict_actors.items():
        if value[0] and value[1] in v:
            aid_fid[key].append(k)
        else:
            aid_fid.update({key:[k]})
```

The output is mostly as I would expect. The beginning of aid_fid looks like this:

```
{10000: [1000], 10001: [1000], 10002: [1000], 10003: [1000], 10004: [1001], 
10005: [1001, 1002], 10006: [1001], 10007: [1001, 1002], 
10015: [1001, 1004]}
```

As you can see the ids of actors who played in multiple of those films are also correctly assigned to the film ids, but after the actor id 10007 it does not go on with 10008 but rather with 10015, and it assigns one wrong value to this key (the 1001 does not belong there). After 10015 it goes on with 10008, 10009 and so on, and correctly adds the right values to those keys. How come the element with the key 10015 are in the wrong place and have the wrong values?

What I think is happening is that it is looking for the strings "Lee" and "J" in the values of my first dict and correctly finds them in the value matching 1004, but it also seems to find those two strings in the value of my key 1001, which should not be the case. Can anyone explain this output to me? Thanks.

Comment: `if value[0] and value[1] in v:` should be `if value[0] in v and value[1] in v:`

Comment: BTW, look up a `defaultdict`: it's an easy way to avoid having to branch on append/update.

Comment: Oh wow, that was a stupid mistake, thanks. And I'll check out defaultdict as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if value[0] and value[1] in v:` checks if `value[0]` is truthy and then checks if `value[1]` is contained in `v`. That's probably not what you wanted to do.

If you want to check if both are contained you should use:

```
if value[0] in v and value[1] in v:
```

or:

```
if all(name_part in v for name_part in value):
```

or if you want to check if they both are contained at the same place in the same order seperated by a whitespace:

```
if " ".join(value) in v:  # checks if e.g. "Lee J" is contained in "v".
```

Comment: `" ".join(value)`, maybe?